# Search iTunes/Appstore by Category or Price

Tags: mac-app-store, itunes-store, itunes-search-api

Is there any chance I can search the Appstore (lets say the Mac Appstore i.e. but I think the search works the same for iTunes or the iOS store) by category or price and get all apps with the given category or price without the limit of 200 results?

What I found is this search query:

http://itunes.apple.com/de/search?entity=macSoftware&term=game&limit=200

(200 is the max limit here, if not set the limit is set to 50 by default)

What I want is something like:

...apple.com/search?entity=macSoftware&category=games

or

...apple.com/search?entity=macSoftware&price=0.99

without limited results.

Any idea how I can get these results? Seems like the official site doesn't help here: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searching

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be better off using the RSS feeds - for Mac App store you can return the top 300 apps per genre.  You can also get narrow down the request to Top Apps (paid or free), Top Paid, Top Free, or Top Grossing:

Top Mac Apps with Games Genre
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmacapps/limit=300/genre=12006/xml

Top Free Mac Apps with Games Genre
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreemacapps/limit=300/genre=12006/xml

The RSS feed generator doesn't expose the sub-genres, but Games has several you can filter down on too:

Top Mac Apps with Card Game Genre
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmacapps/limit=300/genre=12205/xml

RSS feed Generator here:
http://itunes.apple.com/rss

iTunes Genre Index here (scroll all the way down until you see Mac App Store):
http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/genre-mapping.html